# When i bake the mesh on domain, i want to see the waters mesh NOT the shape of the domain mesh, how can i fix this?

Tags: mesh, fluid-simulation, ocean-simulation

So I want to color my fluids on the eevee engine and when I click "bake mesh" when having only the domain selected, instead of giving me a fluid mesh so i can chose the material for the liquid, instead the domain cube just kinda resizes to fit the liquid

Comment: You are using the tags for fluid simulation and ocean simulation, which one is it?

Comment: its kinda both, like its an ocean with a boat sinking and the boat spouts water